# computer turning on at 7:15 every friday

Tags: windows-8.1

My computer turns on at 7:15 every Friday morning. I am running windows 8.1 on this computer. I built this computer myself. I have tried to go into the task scheduler and turning of windows media player on windows 8.1 because i have heard that could be the problem, but the problem still continues.

Comment: Check Disk Defragmenter schedule.

Comment: Check your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your BIOS to see if there is an wake on alarm scheduled. Many BIOS offer this option and this is probably the culprit.